# pytest with spin_until_future_complete doesn't work

Tags: ros2, rclpy, spinning

I've got a short test that works fine with `spin_once`, but not with `spin_until_future_complete`, I probably badly use `Future` object.

Here is my code where I test a message is published on a given topic:

```
class TestMyNode:
    def test_publish_action(s, my_node):
        future = Future()
        my_node.create_subscription(
            String, ACTION_TOPIC,
            lambda msg: setattr(s, 'var', msg) and future.set_result(True),
            qos_profile,
        )
        # this method publish on ACTION_TOPIC
        msg_str = "whatever string"
        my_node.publish_action(msg_str)

        # works fine
        # rclpy.spin_once(my_node, timeout_sec=1.0)
        # works only if i use timeout_sec=2.0 param, but after the 2s delay
        rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(my_node, future)

        assert s.var.data == msg_str
```

Can you tell me what's wrong ?